# xlLastCell only works half of the time

Tags: ms-access, excel, vba

I am trying to remove the duplicates in excel via the following code:

```
Set rng = Range("A1", Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
    rng.removeduplicates Columns:=8, Header:=xlYes
```

This method seems to work half of the time. Sometimes it works, sometimes it gives me the following error:

[image]

Searching on run-time error 1004 gives me the info that there shouldn't be strings, with more than 911 chars, which is not the case. When running the code multiple times on the same excel file, it goes well around 50 percent of the time.

I am running the code in ms access 2007, but all my references are switched on. The question is ofcourse, how to solve this, but any other, better way to easily remove my duplicates will be appreciated as well. Thank you.

**EDIT:** Full code:

```
Const xlLastCell As Long = 11
Const xlYes As Long = 1

Public Function formatreports(FileName As String) As String
Dim xl As Excel.Application
Dim xlwb As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlsh As Excel.Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim newname As String

Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.DisplayAlerts = False
xl.Visible = False

Set xlwb = xl.Workbooks.Open(FileName)
Set xlsh = xlwb.Worksheets(1)

    'its MFR0004; This is solely for import reasons
    xlsh.Rows("1:4").Delete
    xlsh.Rows("2").Delete
    xlsh.Columns("A:B").Delete
    xlsh.Columns("B").Delete
    'This as well
    xlsh.Range("J1") = "Total Weight"
    xlsh.Range("L1") = "Net Weight"
    xlsh.Range("O1") = "Gross Weight"
    xlsh.Range("AA1") = "Delivery Date"

    Set rng = xlsh.Range("A1", Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
    rng.removeduplicates Columns:=8, Header:=xlYes

    newname = Left(FileName, Len(FileName) - 4) & ".XLSX"
    xlwb.SaveAs newname, FileFormat:=51
    formatreports = newname

xlwb.Save
xlwb.Close
xl.Quit
Set xl = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your cells are not fully qualified.

You need to try something like this

```
' change sheet1 to the relevant worksheet
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set rng = .Range("A1", .Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
    rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=8, Header:=xlYes
End With
```

On A side note: Since you are saying that you are working from Access and this code works sometime that means you are maybe using Early Binding. If you are not then you will have to add these to the top of your code

```
Const xlLastCell As Long = 11
Const xlYes As Long = 1
```

Comment: Even though both answers are completely on the mark, it did not solve my problem. It still only works half of the time. I have my posted my full code/function for more information. And how can I check if I am using Early Binding or anything of the sort? Many thanks!

Comment: You are missing the `xlsh.` before the second `Range("A1")` in `Set rng = xlsh.Range("A1", Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell))` See how i have a DOT in my above code.

Comment: Oops, I overlooked that bit! Thank you very much. Solved!